# XSS echoed in pages html code but no pop up window

Tags: xss

So i have a https login page with standard username and password inputs. I put in simple xss test such as,

alert(‘XSS attack’)

the page displays a "credentials you have supplied are incorrect" warning. I dont get a pop up window but the whole line is reflected in html code. Is this still xss or?

Comment: you should try <script type="text/javascript">alert(‘XSS attack’);</script> to let the browser know, that your string should be executed ;)

Answer (score 2):

With an XSS attack you normaly try to put JavaScript Code on a website.

In your example a user tries to log in and on the next page there may be a warning like 'Username [input string] is not valid'.

Now if you try to log in as `alert(‘XSS attack’)` it would **not** be considered as a xss attack because the browser doesn't even recognizes your input as JavaScript - it is just an ordinary string. The example warning from above on the page will look like this:

'Username alert(‘XSS attack’) is not valid'

But if you enter something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert("XSS");</script>
```

the browser will recognize it as JS, and likely evaluate it. The warning would look like this:

'Username  is not valid' (this is because JS will not be shown on the page)

**Conclusion**: Only by sing the `script` tags you will get a browser to recognize a string as JavaScript and therefore only with these tags your popup will show.

**Update:**

As your comment states, the input will only be printed in the value of the textbox, the approach won't work, as textboxes escape the values automatically.

But you could try this as username: `" autofocus onfocus="alert(1)`, so the box markup will change from this:

```
<input type="text" name="loginidtextbox" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

to this:

```
<input type="text" name="loginidtextbox" value="" autofocus onfocus="alert(1)" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: I forgot to add, I did put hte script tags, put the post wouldnt let me include them the way i had them typed. so it was script alert(‘XSS attack’) /script

Comment: That won't work. If the inputfield won't let you type < or > than you can hardly use an XSS attack on the website. But you could check if the input validation is only done with JavaScript and if so disable it and try again.

Comment: I used the < and > and it reflected the whole line still.

Comment: @Ben the site uses some kind of filter, if you post the source code we can say if it is good, or if an attacker can get around it. But without code it is hard to say. For possible ways around some filters, see this [owasp xss cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Perhaps the use something like `htmlentites`. You could check the source, if the '<' got changed to '&lt;' serverside. In this case, you see it as string on the page.

Comment: I entered the following, (                                  <p align="left"><input type="text" name="loginidtextbox" value="<script type="text/javascript">alert("XSS");</script>" autocomplete="off"></p>) minus the ( ).  and it was reflected unmodified in pages html                                   <p align="left"><input type="text" name="loginidtextbox" value="<script type="text/javascript">alert("XSS");</script>" autocomplete="off"></p>

Comment: @Ben see my edit

Comment: @Tokk, so page starts out blank, username html reads ( <p>User ID:</p> 
        <input type="text" value="" name="loginidtextbox" id="loginidtextbox" class="txt-field" autocomplete="off" />  )   .... I then input (   <script type="text/javascript">alert("XSS");</script>  ) and check html and see... ( <input type="text" name="loginidtextbox" value="<script type="text/javascript">alert("XSS");</script>" autocomplete="off">  ) but no pop up window.

Comment: Well @Ben you should really look at my edit of my answer